# ActionLink with ajax enabled get's invoked as a normal GET

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a page, that should update a "process" kinda window when an action is aplied. Kinda like a visible log. Click "start upload" and the div tag underneath will be updated with information.

The problem is, that when i click the "start upload" link it just jumps to that page and don't do a ajax call and update the div.

Controller

```
public ActionResult ProcessWindow(decimal id)
{
    IMG_SETTINGS_FOLDERS img_settings_folders = db.IMG_SETTINGS_FOLDERS.
        Single(i => i.SETTINGS_FOLDER_ID == id);
    return PartialView("ProcessWindow", img_settings_folders);
}
```

View

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Start upload", "ProcessWindow", 
    new { id = Model.SETTINGS_FOLDER_ID }, 
    new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "processWindowssssss" })

<div id="processWindowssssss"></div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.Net MVC AJAX link not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934745/asp-net-mvc-ajax-link-not-working)

Comment: Doesn't seems like a duplicate, mine doesn't fire a ajax request, it just fires a request. Seem like the "ajax" isn't aplied some how. Even through i can see in the source that it compiles like this

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js">
----
<a href="/Upload/ProcessWindow/4" data-ajax-update="#processWindowssssss" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax="true">Start upload</a>
<div id="processWindowssssss"> </div>

Comment: have you added in your web.config under `<appSettings>`, `<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />`

Comment: And a run through firebug also tells me that all JS files are loaded

Comment: Ensure your script refs are above your Ajax call

Comment: Basic HTML yes... i have my script "links" in my head section and the call in the body ;)

Comment: Solved...

When you use unobtrusive ajax, you need to inlcude "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"... If people who rite toturials should read this, please exstend you "js" include info to contain this information to.

Answer found from Brad Wilson on Unobtrusive Ajax.
http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-ajax.html

\T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved...

When you use unobtrusive ajax, you need to include "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"...

If people who write toturials were to read this, please extend your "js" include info to contain this information too.

Answer found from Brad Wilson on Unobtrusive Ajax. http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-ajax.html

\T